# CountVectorizer fit_transform error: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nltk

I am aiming to run a bag of words analysis on multiple .txt documents that I have OCRed from PDFs. I have cleaned all the .txt documents using nltk (made everything lower case, removed binding words like "the", "a" etc, and lammatized to ensure only the word stem remain) then I have saved the .txt files in a CSV with a row for each document with a column with the document name and then a column for every single individual word.

- Each row has a cell with the file name and then "help" "town" etc. in each cell

I am now trying to use countvectorizer and fit_transform to get a matrix of 1s and 0s of how often each variable (word) is used for each row (.txt file).

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize


file_names = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\erlen\Test 2\test 3")

# Create Dictionary for File Name and Text
file_name_and_text = {}
for file in file_names:
    with open(r"C:\Users\Test 2\test 3\\" + file, "r") as target_file:
         file_name_and_text[file] = word_tokenize(target_file.read())


file_data = (pd.DataFrame.from_dict(file_name_and_text, orient='index')
             .reset_index().rename(index = str, columns = {'index': 'file_name', 0: 'text'}))


file_data.to_csv('LIST OF TEXT.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)


# creating the feature matrix
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
matrix = CountVectorizer(max_features=10000, lowercase=False)
X = matrix.fit_transform(file_data).toarray()

#ADD A COLUMN OF 1s to represent YES (target) and NO (non-target)
file_data["investment"] = 1
```

I have tried multiple solutions that I found on here but with no luck. This includes converting file_data with:
str(file_data)
[file_data]
.fillna("")

Also tried removing toarray() and that is not the problem

None of these have worked so far so a bit at a loss of what the issue is. I have looked through the data as well and limited the .txt files to only one/two files for testing so I can look through and I get the same error without a single missing value (when there is only one .txt file).

This is the .head of my file (with words replaced by synonyms)

```
<bound method NDFrame.head of                 file_name          text              1  ...     5456    5457   5458
0         test_1.txt          face  many  ...  place  tool  other
```

Full error message I get for the row "X = matrix.fit_transform(file_data).toarray()":

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/test file only.py", line 25, in <module>
    X = matrix.fit_transform(file_data).toarray()
  File "C:\Users\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 1202, in fit_transform
    vocabulary, X = self._count_vocab(raw_documents,
  File "C:\Users\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 1114, in _count_vocab
    for feature in analyze(doc):
  File "C:\Users\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 106, in _analyze
    doc = tokenizer(doc)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

running file_name.dtypes says they are all objects

```
  file_name    object
text         object
1            object
2            object
3            object
              ...  
5454         object
5455         object
5456         object
5457         object
5458         object
Length: 5460, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up finding a solution (or at least a work around) to this problem. Instead of importing the files first into a pandas frame I imported them directly through the CountVectorizer function:

```
# creating the feature matrix
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
matrix = CountVectorizer(input = 'filename', max_features=10000, lowercase=False)
feature_variables = matrix.fit_transform(file_locations).toarray()
```

I am not 100% sure what the original issue is but hopefully this can help anyone who has a similar issue. Note this exact code requires files to be in the .py file you are running's folder. But this can be easily changed.

If not I have a suspicion it could be because of differences between pandas and numpy dataframes and commands.